# Losing event when reactor is switching scheduler

Tags: spring, project-reactor, reactor-netty, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

**Context:** Loading and streaming Excel file as Flux. Processing Flux records and inserting them into database using R2DBC.

```
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.2") - apache lib which has excel domain of workbooks/sheets/rows/cells
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2")
implementation("com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0") - streamer wrapper which avoids loading entire excel file into the memory and parses chunks of a file
```

Converting file to Flux (extract header as first row and then glue it to every subsequent event/row coming from Flux):

```
override fun extract(inputStream: InputStream): Flux<Map<String, String>> {
        val workbook: Workbook = StreamingReader.builder()
                .rowCacheSize(10) // number of rows to keep in memory (defaults to 10)
                .bufferSize(4096) // buffer size to use when reading InputStream to file (defaults to 1024)
                .open(inputStream)

        val xsltRows = Flux.fromIterable(workbook).flatMap { Flux.fromIterable(it) }

        return xsltRows.next()
                .map { rowToHeader(it) }
                .flatMapMany { header -> xsltRows.map { combineToMap(header, it) } }
    }
```

Subsequently I process this Flux into domain models for Spring R2DBC repositories and insert the entries into MySQL database.

**The problem:** I am missing a single Excel row (out of roughly 2 k). It is always the same row, but nothing special about data in this row.

Recall `combineToMap` method that associates name from the header with every cell value, **it also prints the row logical sequence number as in the file**:

```
private fun combineToMap(header: Map<Int, String>, row: Row): Map<String, String> {

        val mapRow: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf()
        val logicalRowNum = row.rowNum+1

        logger.info("Processing row: $logicalRowNum")

        for (cell in row) {
            if (cell.columnIndex >= header.keys.size) {
                continue
            }

            val headerName = header[cell.columnIndex].takeUnless { it.isNullOrBlank() }
                             ?: throw IllegalStateException("No header name for ${cell.columnIndex} column index for header " +
                                                            "$header and cell ${cell.stringCellValue} row index ${row.rowNum}")

            mapRow[headerName] = cell.stringCellValue
            mapRow["row"] = logicalRowNum.toString()

        }


        return mapRow
    }
```

When I added the log line I noticed the following:

```
2020-11-22 15:49:56.684  INFO 20034 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 255
2020-11-22 15:49:56.687  INFO 20034 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 256
2020-11-22 15:49:56.689  INFO 20034 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 257
2020-11-22 15:50:02.458  INFO 20034 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-1] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 259
2020-11-22 15:50:02.534  INFO 20034 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-1] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 260
2020-11-22 15:50:02.608  INFO 20034 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-1] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 261
```

Note that the scheduler is switched after 257 row, during the switch I lost 258 row. The pool:

```
tor-tcp-epoll-1
```

is understand is Spring R2DBC internal pool.

In my downstream, if instead of doing `repository.save` I return static `Mono.just(entity)` I get my 258 row back, notice the scheduler wasn't switched as well.

```
2020-11-22 16:01:14.000  INFO 21959 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 257
2020-11-22 16:01:14.006  INFO 21959 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 258
2020-11-22 16:01:14.009  INFO 21959 --- [    Test worker] c.b.XSLXFileRecordsExtractor    : Processing row: 259
```

**Is this a problem with the Excel libraries or my implementation? Why am I losing the record when TP is switched?**

P.S. I am not specifying any schedulers or parallel blocks or anything to mess with threads anywhere in my flow apart from calling Spring R2DBC repositories.

I will attempt to rewrite using `implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.8")` and observe if same happens, but if anyone can spot anything obvious or experienced similar elsewhere, I would be infinitely grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched to `commons-csv` which does not have the same problem:

```
2020-11-22 18:34:03.719  INFO 15733 --- [    Test worker] c.b.CSVFileRecordsExtractor     : Processing row: 256
2020-11-22 18:34:09.062  INFO 15733 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-1] c.b.CSVFileRecordsExtractor     : Processing row: 257
2020-11-22 18:34:09.088  INFO 15733 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-1] c.b.CSVFileRecordsExtractor     : Processing row: 258
```

For original approach, I tried to publish all on one scheduler for `xlsx-streamer` and `poi` , even forced Spring R2DBC to publish on the same single thread scheduler and it still skipped the record.

What I could observe is that when database callbacks start to come regardless of which thread pool, this is exact moment when the record gets lost , seems that iterator context gets broken.

I mean the xslx library never claimed to be reactive so no expectations there.